# XSLT: Grouping adjacent elements with same class

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping

I'm new to XSLT and I'm stuck on the "grouping adjacent elements" problem.
My XML input follows the schema:

```
<body>
<aside class="1">
   some tags + text
</aside>
<aside class="2">
    some tags + text
</aside>
<aside class="2">
    some tags + text
</aside>
<p>...</p>
<img .../>
<aside class="2">
    some tags + text
</aside>
<aside class="2">
    some tags + text
</aside>
</body>
```

What I need (and can't achieve) is an output in which the **adjacent** `aside` with the same class are grouped together. The desidered output would be like this:

```
<body>
<tag1 class="1">everything contained in the grouped tags</tag1>
<tag2 class="2">everything contained in the grouped tags</tag2>

<p>...</p>
<img.../>

<tag2 class="2">everything contained in the grouped tags</tag2>
</body>
```

The new tags can be managed using variables, and that's fine. But how do I obtain this output? So far, I've obtained the best results with this:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body">
     <xsl:for-each-group select="aside" group-adjacent="@class">
        <xsl:variable name="grouping_tag">
           <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="@class = '1'">tag1</xsl:when>
               <xsl:when test="@class = '2'">tag2</xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>tagX</xsl:otherwise>
           </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:variable>
       <xsl:element name="{$grouping_tag}" >
            <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="@class"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()/*">                    
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each> 
       </xsl:element>           
     </xsl:for-each-group>

</xsl:template>
```

This solution does indeed group adjacent `aside` with the same class, but in the output I lost everything that is not contained in them (for example, `p`, `img`). And I need to mantain everything else, and in the same position.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please post a well-formed XML input example and the **exact** expected result.

Comment: I posted just what was needed to understand the problem. I need a solution that works always, non in a specific case. Expected result: intead of having <aside class="1>content that can vary</aside> <aside class="1"> content that can vary</aside>, I want to have <newTag class="1"> content of the first aside + content of the second aside </newTag>, but only if the <aside> are adjacent and have the same class. Why do you say the XML is not well-formed?

Comment: Because `<img.../>` produces an error. The purpose of providing an example input is to allow us to test our answers. An input that produces an error wastes our time. Also if you have "some tags + text" but your example does not actually have any descendant elements, then we cannot be sure that the answer provides the expected result, unless we add them ourselves - again, wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `select="*" group-adjacent=". instance of element(aside), @class" composite="yes"` and then you can test `current-group()[1]` to check the group has `aside` elements and wrap them, otherwise push the group through apply-templates.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
<xsl:template match="body">
     <xsl:for-each-group select="aside" group-adjacent="@class">
        <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="@class">
               <xsl:element name="tag{@class}">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
               </xsl:element>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
           </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>     
     </xsl:for-each-group>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I've tested it right now, but it seems that in the output I loose everything not wrapped in an <aside>. So <p>, <img>, and so on are gone (I have a template for the identity transformation, quite useless though).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::aside)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="@class">
                        <xsl:element name="tag{if (@class=(1,2)) then @class else 'X'}" >
                            <xsl:attribute name="class" select="@class"/>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/node()"/>                  
                        </xsl:element>  
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>                 
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

P.S. If `aside` elements are the only child elements of `body` that have a (non-empty) `class` attribute, then you could shorten this to:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="string(@class)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@class">
                    <xsl:element name="tag{if (@class=(1,2)) then @class else 'X'}" >
                        <xsl:attribute name="class" select="@class"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/node()"/>                    
                    </xsl:element>  
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>                    
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```